# Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to successfully send to **multiple** addresses when using Laravel's `Mail::send()` callback, the code does however work when I only specify **one** recipient.

I've tried chaining:

```
// for example
$emails = array("myemail1@email.com", "myemail2@email.com");
$input = Input::all();

Mail::send('emails.admin-company', array('body' => Input::get('email_body')), 
function($message) use ($emails, $input) {
    $message
    ->from('admin@admin.org', 'Administrator')
    ->subject('Admin Subject');

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $message->to($email);
        }
});
```

and passing an array:

```
// for example
$emails = array("myemail1@email.com", "myemail2@email.com");
$input = Input::all();

Mail::send('emails.admin-company', array('body' => Input::get('email_body')), 
    function($message) use ($emails, $input) {
        $message
        ->from('admin@admin.org', 'Administrator')
        ->subject('Admin Subject');

        $message->to($emails);
});
```

but neither seem to work and I get failure messages when returning Mail::failures(), a var_dump() of Mail::failures() shows the email addresses that I tried to send to, for example:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "myemail1@email.com"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "myemail2@email.com"
}
```

Clearly doing something wrong, would appreciate any help as I'm not understanding the API either: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Mail/Message.html#method_to

I realise I could put the `Mail::send()` method in a for/foreach loop and `Mail::send()` for each email address, but this doesn't appear to me to be the optimal solution, I was hoping I would also be able to `->bcc()` to all addresses once everything was working so the recipients wouldn't see who else the mail is being sent to.

Comment: Show more code. Have you tried to insert there existing emails. What failure messages you get?

Comment: What do you mean by existing emails? I am sending it to valid email addresses if that's what you mean? Will add more code with the failure messages. Thanks.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I've tested it using the following code:

```
$emails = ['myoneemail@esomething.com', 'myother@esomething.com','myother2@esomething.com'];

Mail::send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) use ($emails)
{    
    $message->to($emails)->subject('This is test e-mail');    
});
var_dump( Mail:: failures());
exit;
```

Result - empty array for failures.

But of course you need to configure your `app/config/mail.php` properly. So first make sure you can send e-mail just to one user and then test your code with many users.

Moreover using this simple code none of my e-mails were delivered to free mail accounts, I got only emails to inboxes that I have on my paid hosting accounts, so probably they were caught by some filters (it's maybe simple topic/content issue but I mentioned it just in case you haven't received some of e-mails) .

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Apparently I wasn't doing anything wrong, but my IP at work wasn't enabled to relay email outside of our domain! All sorted and working now. Thanks again.

Comment: @haakym That's why if something doesn't work, you should always try to use the simplest code and make sure it works without a problem. Often problems are not where you expect them to be.

Comment: If i want to write somewhere the name of the receipts, how i can do this?

Comment: this does _not_ work any longer with laravel 5.3 because mailable tries to access `->email` and results in `ErrorException in Mailable.php line 376:
Trying to get property of non-object` a working code for laravel 5.3 is  ... i actually will create my answer because it looks messy here. But feel free to add my answer to your accepted answer. My answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39734742/533426

Comment: Tested in Laravel 5.6, all working. However the array needs to be created, if you are pulling emails data from another table, run a `foreach` and `array_push` to a new array.

Comment: Or just get an array of emails like this `$myCollection->pluck('emailCol')->toArray();`

Comment: Works fine. but into part of the received email, there is a list of all emails visible, how can I hide the user's email from that details.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to send emails simultaneously to all the admins, you can do something like this:

In your .env file add all the emails as comma separated values:

```
ADMIN_EMAILS=admin1@site.com,admin2@site.com,admin3@site.com
```

so when you going to send the email just do this (yes! the 'to' method of message builder instance accepts an array):

So,

```
$to = explode(',', env('ADMIN_EMAILS'));
```

and...

```
$message->to($to);
```

will now send the mail to all the admins.

Comment: Best answer for usage of .env file

Comment: You shouldn't reference the ENV directly - use the config helper.

Comment: Top answer here.

Comment: There are 2 ways how to achieve to be able to changes email adresses without changing code. You go either with .env file or via Eloquent / table but for the latter you need to think about table structures, so .env is the most simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 14):

With Laravel 5.6, if you want pass multiple emails with names, you need to pass array of associative arrays. Example pushing multiple recipients into the `$to` array:

```
$to[] = array('email' => $email, 'name' => $name);
```

Fixed two recipients:

```
$to = [['email' => 'user.one@example.com', 'name' => 'User One'], 
       ['email' => 'user.two@example.com', 'name' => 'User Two']];
```

The 'name' key is not mandatory. You can set it to `'name' => NULL` or do not add to the associative array, then only `'email'` will be used.

Comment: it gives me this error:
`Address in mailbox given [email] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.`

Comment: This works with Laravel 8+ too

Answer (score 13):

the accepted answer does *not* work any longer with laravel 5.3 because mailable tries to access `->email` and results in

> ErrorException in Mailable.php line 376: Trying to get property of
>   non-object

a working code for laravel 5.3 is this:

```
$users_temp = explode(',', 'first@example.com,second@example.com');
    $users = [];
    foreach($users_temp as $key => $ut){
      $ua = [];
      $ua['email'] = $ut;
      $ua['name'] = 'test';
      $users[$key] = (object)$ua;
    }
 Mail::to($users)->send(new OrderAdminSendInvoice($o));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Saved me a lot of time and grief. Is this change intentional because it seems like too much code for something that should be very short hand. I am defining my to() function using a variable `$to = [(object) ['name' => 'Example Name', 'email' => 'test@example.com'], (object) ['name' => 'Example Name 2', 'email' => 'test2@example.com']];`

Answer (score 12):

In a scenario where you intend to push a single email to different recipients at one instance (i.e CC multiple email addresses), the solution below works fine with **Laravel 5.4 and above**.

```
Mail::to('dunsin.olubobokun@domain.com')
    ->cc(['paul.yomi@domain.com','stack.overflow@domain.com','abc.xyz@domain.com','nigeria@domain.com'])
    ->send(new document());
```

where **document** is any class that further customizes your email.

Answer (score 7):

You can loop over recipientce like:

```
foreach (['taylor@example.com', 'dries@example.com'] as $recipient) {
    Mail::to($recipient)->send(new OrderShipped($order));
}
```

See documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#sending-mail)

Comment: I prefer this way as it also works with queue: Mail::to($recipient)->queue(...);

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel 5.6 and the Notifications Facade.

If I set a variable with comma separating the e-mails and try to send it, I get the error:
"Address in mail given does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2"

So, to solve the problem, I got the solution idea from @Toskan, coding the following.

```
        // Get data from Database
        $contacts = Contacts::select('email')
            ->get();

        // Create an array element
        $contactList = [];
        $i=0;

        // Fill the array element
        foreach($contacts as $contact){
            $contactList[$i] = $contact->email;
            $i++;
        }

        .
        .
        .

        \Mail::send('emails.template', ['templateTitle'=>$templateTitle, 'templateMessage'=>$templateMessage, 'templateSalutation'=>$templateSalutation, 'templateCopyright'=>$templateCopyright], function($message) use($emailReply, $nameReply, $contactList) {
                $message->from('myemail@somecompany.com', 'Some Company Name')
                        ->replyTo($emailReply, $nameReply)
                        ->bcc($contactList, 'Contact List')
                        ->subject("Subject title");
            });
```

It worked for me to send to one or many recipients.

Comment: Instead of creating an array element you can just have it as Contacts::pluck('email')->toArray()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$toemail = explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $request->toemail));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing in one of my multi-vendor e-commerce projects.

```
$vendorEmails[0]    =    'myemail@gmail.com';
    foreach ($this->order->products as $orderProduct){
        $vendorEmails[$count] = \App\User::find($orderProduct->user_id)->email;
        $count++;
    }

    return $this->from('from_email_@gmail.com', 'Made In India')
        ->to($this->order->billing_email, $this->order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $this->order->billing_last_name)
        ->bcc('bcc@email.com')
        ->cc($vendorEmails)
        ->subject('Order Placed Successfully - Made In India - ' . $this->order->generated_order_id)
        ->markdown('emails.orderplaced');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This options works for me when sending dynamic email as a variable

```
$emails = ['yenemmanuel@gmail.com', $email];                                                    Mail::send('emails.patchmail', [], function($message) use ($emails)
     {    
     $message->to($emails)->subject('PATCH BIKER REG')->from('customer-service@patch.com.ng', 'Patch Global'); });
```

Also includes the senders email

Answer (score 0):

public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
$users = User::whereIn("id", $request->ids)->get();

```
    foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new UserEmail($user));
    }

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Send email successfully.']);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This works great - i have access to the request object and the email array

```
        $emails = ['tester@blahdomain.com', 'anotheremail@blahdomian.com'];
        Mail::send('emails.lead', ['name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone], function ($message) use ($request, $emails)
        {
            $message->from('no-reply@yourdomain.com', 'Joe Smoe');
//            $message->to( $request->input('email') );
            $message->to( $emails);
            //Add a subject
            $message->subject("New Email From Your site");
        });
```

Comment: How I can use ```$message->to($emails);``` but include the name of the recipents?

Comment: @JCarlos have the email be the key of the associative array, `['email@email.com' => 'Joe', 'email2@email.com' => 'Jack']`

Answer (score -15):

it works for me fine,
if you a have string, then simply explode it first.

$emails = array();

```
Mail::send('emails.maintenance',$mail_params, function($message) use ($emails) {
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $message->to($email);
    }

    $message->subject('My Email');
});
```

Comment: This would send N emails to N recipients. The goal is to send 1 email to N recipients.

Comment: ^ for that, use what @Grant mentioned on an answer below, an associative array `['email@email.com' => 'Joe', 'email2@email.com' => 'Jack']`.