# Trying to send email to multiple users in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I want to send email to multiple users. Here is my email sending code.

```
   $email_id =  User::select('email_id')->get();  
   Mail::send('test' , array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) {     
      $message -> to('xyz@gmail.com') -> subject ('Welcome!!!');
});
```

I am getting array of email_id while printing `$email_id` and I pass `$email_id` to array. but it's not working.

Any help would be grateful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $email_id =  User::select('email_id')->get()->toArray();  
    Mail::send('test' , array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) {     
    $message -> to('xyz@gmail.com') -> subject ('Welcome!!!');
});
```

Comment: not working. I have tried using                                                                                                                  `$email_id =  User::select('email_id')->get();

        Mail::send('mail', [], function($message) use ($email_id)
        {
            $message->to($email_id)->subject('Welcome!!!');
        }); ` But it's not working , too

Comment: What is the value of $email_id? Is it an array of strings?

Comment: `$email_id =  User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id');`                                          When I run this. I get values like this. `["xyz@abc.com","abc@abc.com","qwerty@abc.com"]`. and when i try to send using these values I get error of Illegal Offset Type. But when i write like this     `$email_id = ["xyz@abc.com","abc@abc.com","qwerty@abc.com"];` . I get the expected result that is mail is sent to multiple users.

Comment: $email_id = User::select('email_id')->get()->pluck('email_id'); Mail::send('test', array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) { $message->from('from@example.com'), 'From Example Name'); $message->to('xyz@gmail.com')->subject('Welcome!!!'); })

This code send ONLY ONE email to xyz@gmail.com

Comment: If you want to send the email to multiple users use:

$email_id =  User::select('email')->get()->pluck('email')->toArray();
        Mail::send('test', array('user' => $email_id) , function ($message) use ($email_id) {
            $message->from('from@example.com'), 'From Example Name'); 
            $message->to($email_id)->subject('Welcome!!!');
        });

Both codes work, if you get errors, maybe the problem is the template you are using. Check this.

Answer (score 1):

Please check mention url you can use this

[Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

https://codedump.io/share/7tL5qbeUwnKT/1/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses