# How to send multiple emails using Mailgun in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, mailgun

I tried this code:

```
$message->to(array(
                    'bb@gmail.com',
                    'zz@gmail.com'
                ));

$message->from('foo@example.com', 'Recipient Name');
$message->subject('Welcome!');
```

I get error:

> The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!
>   Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own
>   domain or add the address to authorized recipients in domain settings.

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear. Read up: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients

Comment: Set this comment as answer, it is solution

Comment: No! delete this, OP should do research first! Ask later. RTFM RTFM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
$receivers = ['bb@gmail.com', 'zz@gmail.com'];
Mail::send('your_theme', [], function($message) use ($receivers)
{    
    $message->to($receivers)->subject('Welcome!');    
});
var_dump( Mail:: failures());
exit;
```

This works on my laravel 4.2, not sure about later versions.
Source : [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)