# Laravel 5.3 send Mail to multiple email-adresses

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and trying to send a newsletter Mail to specific mail adresses.

Currently I do the following:

```
$newsletterMailAdresses = Newsletter::where('user_id', $userID)->pluck('mailAdress');
```

This returns an array of email-adresses, to which the emails shouuld be sent.

What I then (normally) use to send mails is:

```
Mail::to("someMailAdress")->send(new newsletterMail($newsletterText));
```

I thought about just passing that array into the `to` function but I'm quite sure it won't work.... What you propably could do, is a foreach with every mail adress and send the mails, but is this the way how this should be done or is there a better way?

PS: I know [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses) thread but its about Laravel 4, so there are many things changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work, when you pass an array. Check the reference:

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Mail/Message.html#method_to

The first parameter can be an array. Try it.

Comment: Oh great, you're absolutely right, it seems to be that easy. Thank you!

Comment: Just one thing that's missing, I'm using TinyMCE to create the newsletter text, so the variable `$newsletterText` holds HTML, so far I get the html in the mail, so not "compiled" html, how can I change this?

Comment: Okay, got it, needed to use the `!!`in the blade template

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work, but you can also try to do like this:

```
     Mail::raw('No Body', function($message) use ($emails)
      {    
        foreach ($emails as $email)
         {
           $message->to($email); 
         }   
      });
```

I use like this in my application and it works fine!

Maybe you can also try to send one email and vereify it works fine, then you can try sending the email using the array of emails.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mail::to(['array','of','emails'])...
```

also

```
Mail::cc(['array','of','emails'])...
```

and

```
Mail::bcc(['array','of','emails'])...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Laravel 5.4 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#sending-mail) on Sending Mail:

> The ***to*** method accepts an email address, a user instance, or a collection of users. If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their email and name properties when setting the email recipients, so make sure these attributes are available on your objects.