# Laravel send mail to multiple recipients with the "Name" of recipient

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

We can send mails to multiple recipients by passing the array of recipients in the $message->to() function of mail. There is the solution to send the multiple recipients but it does not include names, it just include email id's. [Send Mail to Multiple Recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

But how can I add the names of these recipients which are in array to the mail. 
For Example: When I send a mail to single recipient then its like where we can pass the second parameter as name of the recipient.

```
$message->to("alex_test@gmail.com", "Alex");
```

But when I send the mail to multiple recipients the its like:

```
$emails = ['email@esomething.com', 'email1@esomething.com','email2@esomething.com'];

Mail::send('emails.welcome', [], function($message) use ($emails)
{    
    $message->to($emails)->subject('This is test e-mail');    
});
```

Is there a way that I can add the names of the recipients to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

Comment: @Rahul : You were in a hurry to call it a duplicate. My question addresses a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to send the emails and names as an associative array?

Eg.

```
$emails = [
    'email@esomething.com'=>'Name', 
    'email1@esomething.com'=>'Name1',
    'email2@esomething.com'=>'Name2
];
```

I haven't tried this but according to [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) `setTo()`, this can be done.

Hopefully that works.

Answer (score 1):

you can use bcc

```
Mail::send('mail', array('key' => $todos1), function($message) {
$message->to('Hello@example.com')
->bcc(array('TEST@example.com','TEST1@example.com','TEST2@example.com','TEST3@example.com'))
->subject('Welcome!');
```

});

Comment: If I would like to add the name of the recipients in the email then how it can be done. For Ex: You have passed TEST@example.com in array, but if i would like to add his name as "TEST" in email then how it can be done.

Comment: $message->from($address, $name = null);
$message->sender($address, $name = null);
$message->to($address, $name = null);
$message->cc($address, $name = null);
$message->bcc($address, $name = null);
$message->replyTo($address, $name = null);
$message->subject($subject);
$message->priority($level);
$message->attach($pathToFile, array $options = []);

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, with Laravel 5.6:

```
$to = [
    ['email' => 'email_1@esomething.com', 'name' => 'Name 1'],
    ['email' => 'email_2@esomething.com', 'name' => 'Name 2']
];
```