# Explode a string into an array with assigned value and send the email to multiple reciepient

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email

I have a string declared as shown below

```
var email = 'xxx@email.com,ggg@gmail.com'
```

I am using explode to make it as an array

```
$emails = explode(",", $user->email);
```

With the $emails output like

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "xxx@email.com"
  1 => "ggg@gmail.com"
]
```

What i am expected is

```
$a = array('xxx@email.com'=>'abc','ggg@gmail.com'=>'cde');

Result:

array:2 [▼
  "xxx@email.com"=> "abc"
  "ggg@gmail.com"=> "cde"
]
```

I want to send email to multiple recipient with the name of recipient.e.g

```
abc(xxx@email.com);cde(ggg@gmail.com)
```

It works fine when mail->to a single recipient

```
mail->to('xxx@email.com','abc');
```

Can anyone tell me how can i make it to send an email to multiple recipient with name as well?

Comment: I suppose you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39734742/4020014

Comment: I tried but not working.

Comment: None of the answers is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try using `foreach` ? For example :

```
foreach($a as $key=>$val) {
   mail->to($key, $val);
}
```

### Update

If your string is as what you have stated, maybe you could do like this :

```
$string = "abc(xxx@email.com);cde(ggg@gmail.com)";
$data = explode(';', $string);
$detailsArray = array();

foreach($data as $datax){
    $email = "";
    //Using regex to filter out string with paranthesis
    preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $datax, $email);

    //using str_replace to remove the email together with paranthesis to get the name
    $name = str_replace($email[0], "", $datax);

    //removing paranthesis
    $email[0] = str_replace(array('(',')'),'',$email[0]);

    //push it into array
    $array = array($email[0] => $name);
    array_push($detailsArray,$array );
}
```

Comment: The problem is mentioned above. How can i turn my string into specific key and value? If i am using explode()?

Comment: Oh I am sorry for the misunderstanding, do refer the latest update and hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry mate but this is a very inefficient way to do it. I don't understand the use of $email. First you create it as a string then preg_match makes it array. You use a pattern to remove the (), but yet you don't use that item. You use [0] which is the full match and remove the () from it. Also looping and doing a preg_match on each item will be a pain if it's more than two addresses. With 10 emails it takes 0.5 seconds to load your code.

Comment: I have posted an answer, it may not be the best approach but it's faster. To make your code better you could remove the part that is `removing paranthesis` completely since $email[1] is the same as your result of the str_replace. But even with this change it's not much difference. You are still looping and doing the same code several times.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
It will use preg_match_all to create two arrays, one with names and one with emails.
Then I use array_combine to create the emails array with named keys.

```
$str = "johnny-boy doe(xxx@email.com);cde(ggg@gmail.com)";

Preg_match_all('/([-A-Za-z0-9 ]+)\((.*?)\)/', $str, $match);

$emails = array_combine($match[2], $match[1]);

Var_dump($emails);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["xxx@email.com"] => string(14) "johnny-boy doe"
  ["ggg@gmail.com"] => string(3) "cde"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/shqAe

Edit; had the key and value in the wrong order in emails array.
Edit2; I just remembered that if the name is first and last name my previous code would not have worked. Replaced the \w+ to a wider matching of name.