# How to send multiple emails in laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to send multiple emails. I am using below code to send multiple emails:-

```
$emails = ['ab.in@gmail.com', 'ka.in@gmail.com'];

    Mail::send('emails.email-marketing-template', [], function($message) use ($emails)
    {    
        $message->to($emails)->subject('This is test e-mail');    
    });
    var_dump( Mail:: failures());
    exit;
```

If i send it to single user, it is working, but not for multiple users. How should i send email to multiple user?

Comment: share which code works for single email ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

Answer (score 5):

From [the 5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#sending-mail):

> The to method accepts an email address, a user instance, or **a collection of users**. If you pass an object or collection of objects, the mailer will automatically use their `email` and `name` properties when setting the email recipients, so make sure these attributes are available on your objects.

So, you can do this:

```
$users = User::get();
Mail::to($users)->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```

Or you can pass an array with `name` and `email` keys:

```
$users = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'email' => 'john@gmail.com'],
    ['name' => 'Jane', 'email' => 'jane@gmail.com'],
    ['name' => 'Max', 'email' => 'max@gmail.com'],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer sending emails from Laravel and Symfony by queue/spool. Read more about [queueing emails in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#queueing-mail).

Queue emails are better than sending messages immediately because main process which supports the request is not waiting for email sending process.

If you use `Mail:queue` you can send emails in the loop to many recipients