# How to pass emails array to mail function in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

`$emails` is an array but only shows me one email.

Also how to pass the email array into `info_on_hand` view?

```
$emails=$request['emails'][$i];
Mail::send('emails.info_on_hand', $data, function ($message) use($emails) {
    $message->from('us@example.com', 'Name Company');

    foreach($emails as $email):
        $message->to($emails)->subject('Status: '.Input::get('desc').'  With VIN#  '.Input::get('vin').' is '.Input::get('status').'At Name');
    endforeach;
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

So to send and pass the array of emails to the view and send it to them is like this

Guessing when you return just `$emails` it looks like this:

```
['test@example.com', 'test2@example.com','test3@example.com']
```

If so use this

```
$emails = $request['emails'];
Mail::send('emails.info_on_hand', ['emails' => $emails], function ($m) use ($emails) {
    $m->from('youremail@eample.com', 'Name');
    $m->to($emails);
    $m->subject('Your Subject');
});
```

Another thing is that with the New GDPR laws don't think this is allowed?