# Laravel Mail accessing object in mail view when sending to bulk recipients?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

As the title says I am trying to access recipient when sending bulk mail.

Right now I am doing this, sending to participants collection with info about event, but I also want to access each participant in view.

```
Mail::to($this->participants)->send(new News($this->event));
```

I could do a foreach but I do not think that is efficient.

I need something like this, so I could get the participant in the mail class to send it to view.

```
Mail::to($this->participants)->send(new News($this->event, $this->participant));
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses

Comment: @MaKobi In the link he runs function inside Mail::send() does it send one mail after the function is completed or does it send mail foreach function?