# Sending multiple email(to) using laravel mailable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6 and trying to send email to multiple email address. Here my code works for only one email. How can I use multiple email?
 I am using mailable

Here is my controller

```
public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
    Mail::send(new sendMail());
    Session::flash('conf_email', 'ok');

    return redirect('/send-email');
}
```

```
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    public function build(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->view('mail', ['msg' => $request->message])->to($request->to);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses) what you need?

Comment: Or maybe [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#sending-mail)?

Comment: @kerbholz yeah, that's true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

Comment: @ Muhammad Dyas Yaskur and  mare96. 
Yes. But how can I use body(text) dynamically  ?

Comment: Another issue is i want to use mailable

Comment: Are you wanting to send the same email to multiple people or send each person a personalised email? Also, how are you getting the multiple email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

the to() function accepts multiple users (array of emails(strings) or objects) 
please see the following link for more information 
https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.html#method_to

so you can do something like this

```
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
   public function build(Request $request)
   {
     $users=User::all();
     return $this->view('mail', ['msg' => $request->message])->to($users);
     //or 
      return $this->view('mail', ['msg' => $request->message])->to(['test@test.com','test1@test.com']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You just need to change sendEmail function to:

public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{
    Mail::to(['test@test.com','test1@test.com'])->send(new sendMail()); 
    Session::flash('conf_email', 'ok');

    return redirect('/send-email');
}
```