# Sending email to multiple recipients using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I trying to send emails to multiple recipients. I used the looping to send multiple times but it does not seem to work as I get only 1 email sent. I search the internet for guides but not found anything related to this problem.

```
$mails = User::select('users.name','users.staffid','users.email')->get();

foreach($mails as $mail)
{
    $data[] = [
        'name'     => $mail->name,
        'username' => $mail->staffid,
        'email'    => $mail->email
    ];  
}

foreach($data as $dat)
{
    Mail::send('email.sendReminder', ["data1"=>$dat], function($message) use ($dat) {
        $message->from('test@gmail.com', 'Test Reminder');
        $message->to($dat['email']);
        $message->subject('Reminder');
    });
}
```

Comment: This may answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Mail::send() sending to multiple to or bcc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584904/laravel-mailsend-sending-to-multiple-to-or-bcc-addresses)

Comment: its kinda similar but it helps so yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using queue jobs? you must use it otherwise your server may not respond for multiple email. second you are sending multiple emails at the same time may be you should try this.

```
$mails = User::select('users.name','users.staffid','users.email')->get();

foreach($mails as $dat)
{

Mail::send('email.sendReminder', ["data1"=>$dat], function($message) use ($dat) {
    $message->from('test@gmail.com', 'Test Reminder');
    $message->to($dat['email']);
    $message->subject('Reminder');
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the function into a loop for sending multiple emails. The below code works for me

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'admin.email-template.lowstock'], array('totalUsers' => $totalUsers, 'item' => $item,'data' =>$data), function ($message) use ($user_to_mail, $item) {
                $message->from('POS@gmail.com', 'POS');
                $message->subject('Notification Mail');
                foreach ($user_to_mail as $mail) {
                    $message->to($mail->email);
                }

            });
```