# Cannot Send sperate Emails to user when subscribe and admin Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Hi i have a contact from and everything is so working good so far but i want to send differents emails when subscribe one for the user and one to alert the admin that user is subscribed and show name and email and phone number in that mail

Here is my code

**ContactController.php**

```
 //  Send mail to admin

        \Mail::send('contactMail', array(

            'name' => $input['name'],

            'email' => $input['email'],

            'phone' => $input['phone'],

            'subject' => $input['subject'],

            'message' => $input['message'],

        ), function($message) use ($request){

            $message->from($request->email, $name = 'Carrez Conseil');

            $message->to($request->email, 'Admin')->subject($request->get('subject'));
            $message->to('abde*******@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject($request->get('subject'));

        });


        return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Contact Form Submit Successfully']);
```

Comment: In my opinion you should create separate Mail classes and then perform your desired action.

Comment: Can you explain more ??

Comment: Yes e.g. create one Mail class for User and one for Admin. Then you could use those classes like `Mail::send(new UserMail($input)) `
`Mail::send(new AminMail($input))`. This way your Mail part is separated in its own class and could easily be managed.

Comment: can you show me an example ? because the mail content is in Contactmail.blade.php

Comment: Yes the Markdown needs to be separate for Admin and User. I can direct you some somewhat similar question asked on another forum. That can give you a hint. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/send-two-email-at-once-for-admin-and-user

Comment: Does the mail content for the user and the admin different? If yes, you can use @Ali's suggestion. If not, you can try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26586288/13933721